# In Product Category archives how to show Posts having same/similar prod_cat slug structure?

Tags: wp-query, archives, custom-post-type-archives, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I will be writing Posts about each of Product's Product Categories (product_cat on products) and I am choosing to group (associate) Posts by the product_cat hierarchical taxonomy. To do this without duplicating the taxonomy, I registered it in my functions.php like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_product_cat_taxonomy_for_post_object' );
function register_product_cat_taxonomy_for_post_object() {
     register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product_cat', 'post' ); 
}
```

Much like Category archives, I happen to be using woocommerce which by default lets users browse Product Archives by Product Category. They simply click the provided product_cat breadcumbs and i believe archive-product.php will display a list of products that have a product_cat matching the clicked-on breadcrumb.

I am having trouble with my next objective. I plan to hook-into the `archive-product.php` `do_action( ‘woocommerce_after_main_content’ );` to inject some custom funtionality, but I am having trouble writing the custom functionality. I am looking for help writing two different query/display codes to show:

1) posts whose list of product_cat slugs match at minimum the list of product_cat slugs in the breadcrumbs mentioned above. When I say “posts whose…prouduct_cat slugs” refer to the `register_product_cat_taxonomy_for_post_object()` function above for clarification.

2) posts whose list of product_cat slugs match exactly the list of product_cat slugs in the breadcrumbs mentioned above. When I say “posts whose…prouduct_cat slugs” refer to the `register_product_cat_taxonomy_for_post_object()` function above for clarification.

Ultimately, the goal is for me to write posts, assign posts specific product_cat terms, then figure out #1 and #2 so that users who are breadcrumb-browsing products by product category can also see (via my injection of #1 and #2) posts related to the product category that they are currently breadcrumb-browsing in archive-product.php

Thank you,

Comment: In a nutshell you want to show the posts related to current products `product_cat` below ***WooCommerce*** main content, right ?

Comment: Yeah, but i dont want to hardcode the posts into that injection-location.  I am looking for a programmatic way to build two queries 1) and 2) in OP above.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've written a function for you-

```
function the_dramatist_get_product_cat_posts( $args = array() ) {
    $default_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'get_post_type' => 'post'
    );
    $t = array();
    $param = wp_parse_args($args, $default_args);
    $prod_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), $param['taxonomy']);
    foreach ($prod_terms as $prod_term ) {
        $t[] = $prod_term->term_id;
    }
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $param['get_post_type'],
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $param['taxonomy'],
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $t,
                'include_children' => false
            )
        )
    ));

    return $posts;
}
```

By calling this function like `the_dramatist_get_product_cat_posts()` you'll get all the posts related to current product's `product_cat` taxonomy terms. It will give you all the post object. Then you can run a `foreach` or `for` loop to organize the posts as you like. You can temporarily do a `print_r` on this function to understand the returned data structure. It'll help you to understand the data.

Hope that helps.